# sql server moving number decimal place

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

Afternoon,

I am trying to convert a number padded with zeros to one that resembles a monetary amount in MS SQL.

Here is an example of what I have, and what I want.

Have:
00000000000039570
Want:
395.70

So far I have managed to get rid of the leading zeros with the below code.

```
SUBSTRING ([Balance], PATINDEX ('%[^0 ]%', [Balance] + ' '), LEN([Balance])) AS [Balance]
```

Going back to my example, this would give me '39570'.

Any help on how to get the decimal as well, or a better way of trimming, would be very much appreciated!

Sorry if this has been covered before. I did a few searches but could not see exactly what I was after. I am new here so go easy on me! ;)

Dan

Comment: Can you not convert it to a regular decimal number and divide it by 100?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you should post that as an answer

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26972

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the string to a float and divide by 100:

```
select cast('00000000000039570' as float)/100
```

If you want a string representation:

```
select str(cast('00000000000039570' as float)/100, 15, 2)
```

EDIT:

In light of the comment from dasblinknight, the following is preferable given the size of the string:

```
select cast('00000000000039570' as decimal(19,2))/100
select str(cast('00000000000039570' as decimal(19,2))/100, 15, 2)
```

Comment: Since `float` could potentially become less precise than the original, I think `decimal(19,2)` would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a master of MSSQL but it seems to me after what you did this should work:

```
SUBSTRING([BALANCE], 0, LEN([BALANCE]) - 2) + '.' + SUBSTRING([BALANCE], LEN([BALANCE]) - 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast('00000000000039570' as decimal(19,0))*.01
```